# Apache mod_rewrite for everything except root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I am trying to write a mod_rewrite rule to redirect everything except the root folder.
For example, www.example.com should load the index.html file
For everything else, e.g. www.example.com/tag, the /tag should be passed to a script in a subdirectory

Right now I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

And that loads index.html fine but the /tag is not passed to webroot.  I'm getting a 404 error.

Thanks

Comment: If you change the rewrite rule to RewriteRule (.*) http:/ /yourdomain.com/app/webroot/$1 [L,R] what is the URL that you are redirected to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This condition is the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
```

You're saying anything that starts with '/' is not rewritten, and everything begins with '/'. You need to use `$` at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

I'm not sure you need the rule at all, though, because if index.html exists the other two rules will take care of that automatically. Just use these to rewrite anything that doesn't physically exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And you can handle a 404 error in your app, since you'll have to for the subdirectories anyway.